# Blender 2.82 particle motion blur

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, fluid-simulation, motion-blur

So I'm working on a fluid simulation with the new blender 2.82 features(cycles), where I have foam, spray, and bubbles enabled. All is well and it renders properly until I enable motion blur, which well...

[image]

That's a render time not many are willing to wait for. Note that this only happens with the particles enabled.

Comment: Essentially motion blur works by rendering each frame multiple time (with a slight offset), so yes it takes a lot of time. What you can try is to fake it in compositing, by rendering a Vector pass (which represent the speed of every pixel) and using a Vector Blur node. That's not as precise but REALLY quicker. Warning, I can't confirm it will work well with every types of particles.

Comment: Hmm, I think it might be a bug, I just tried it with a ton of particles outside of the fluid simulation and it seems to work fine. But I guess the vector blur node will do for now.